# Creating a String[] from Guava's Splitter

Tags: java, string, guava

Is there a more efficient way to create a string array from [Guava's Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) than the following?

```
Lists.newArrayList(splitter.split()).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: (Of course, if it's possible to fix that code that wants a String[] to want a List or Iterable instead, much the better.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably not so much more efficient, but a lot clearer would be [`Iterables.toArray(Iterable, Class)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29)

This pretty much does what you do already:

```
public static <T> T[] toArray(Iterable<? extends T> iterable, Class<T> type) {
    Collection<? extends T> collection = toCollection(iterable);
    T[] array = ObjectArrays.newArray(type, collection.size());
    return collection.toArray(array);
}
```

By using the `collection.size()` this should even be a tick faster than creating a zero-length array just for the type information and having `toArray()` create a correctly sized array from that.

Comment: Thanks! The extra detail in the answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, what Kevin said up there. He sure knows why Guava does it that way :)

Answer (score 17):

How about

```
Iterables.toArray(splitter.split(), String.class);
```

since there's an [`Iterables.toArray()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29) method